# how can i dynamically create a docker container from a node application

Tags: node.js, docker

How can i dynamically create a docker container from a node application.?
I tried executing docker commands using exec and spawn with root privilege but it is not working. Can anyone help me find out what is the problem with my code?

```
exec('docker run -it ubuntu14 >> log.log ', function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
  res.send(stdout);
});
```

Comment: what output  do you get? any errors?

Comment: Do you have a command before this that verifies and/or starts your docker client? Are you sure the client is running?

Comment: You should use a wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-cmd

Comment: @KLibby 

No error message but the  docker is not creating the container , all other docker commands such as cp, images rm are working properly 
{{
current output

executing : docker run -it ubuntu14 >> userurl_fact.temporary
executing : docker cp userurl_fact.cpp :/userurl_fact.cpp

expected output

executing : docker run -it ubuntu14 >> userurl_fact.temporary
executing : docker cp userurl_fact.cpp <container id>:/userurl_fact.cpp }}

Comment: @SeeDart yes the commands are running properly when i am using command prompt

Comment: Are you ignoring the error? Add `console.log(error)`

Comment: @Iyjackal { [Error: Command failed: cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }

Comment: Thank you all i finally got the solution  'docker run -t ubuntu14 >> log.log'